# custom error middleware in net core not catching model state errors

Tags: asp.net-core

I have some custom middleware set up to handle errors in my api application.

in `startup.cs` i have got code as follows

```
app.UseErrorHandlingMiddleware(); //this is custom extension method that just does builder.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
app.UseAuthentication;
app.UseMvc();
```

any errors thrown in the application are caught by the middleware but if i send invalid model to a controller action the model state validation error is not getting caught by my middleware. I get a standard 400 bad request response such as:

{"errors":{"Username":["The Username field is required."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"0HLNLAV1FS4IJ:00000002"}

Is there something i need to do to have my middleware get these errors?

The middleware invoke methods is as follows:

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }
```

Do i need to use an ActionFilter to check modelstate and throw exception if error in order for my error middleware to get it?

Comment: a deeper bit of googling has led me to believe my issue is due to the `ApiController` attribute on my controller class. This brings with it some default behaviour.   https://coderethinked.com/customizing-automatic-http-400-error-response-in-asp-net-core-web-apis/

Comment: ModelState errors are not thrown as exceptions. And yes, that attribute sets up some default behaviour around model state. If you disable it, you'll need to check model state validity in your action method or in an action filter.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.